Demonstrate that A is a countable set.
Question: Let $A = \{x \in \Bbb N \mid \exists y(x = 2y \lor  x = y^2)\}$. Construct a surjective mapping $ f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A $. By doing this, you demonstrate that A is a countable set.
Approach: To construct a surjective mapping $ f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A $, we need to ensure that every element in set $ A $ is mapped to from some element in the set of natural numbers $ \mathbb{N} $.
Given the definition of set $ A = \{x \in \mathbb{N} \mid \exists y(x = 2y \lor x = y^2)\} $, we can see that any natural number can be represented either as twice another natural number or as the square of a natural number.
One way to construct a surjective mapping is as follows:
For even numbers $ x $, let $ f(x) = x/2 $.
For odd numbers $ x $, let $ f(x) = \sqrt{x} $.
This mapping ensures that every element in $ A $ is covered.
This demonstrates that $ A $ is a countable set because we can create a one-to-one correspondence between $ A $ and the set of natural numbers $ \mathbb{N} $.
Would this be enough to prove that A is a countable set?

You have gone wrong at the start. The question asks for a mapping $ f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A $ but your one goes $ f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{N} $.

And it is not true that " any natural number can be represented either as twice another natural number or as the square of a natural". You mean presumably "...any natural number in $A$ can be represented either as....".

$A$ is the set of even natural numbers, union with the set of square numbers, correct? So $A$ can also be written as the disjoint union of $B$ and $C,$ where $B$ is the set of odd squares and $C$ is the set of even natural numbers.

Since you don’t need $f$ to be bijective, you have a lot of “wiggle room” to work with.
If $n$ is even, define $f(n)=n$.  If $n$ is an odd square, define $f(n)=n$.  If $n$ is odd but not a square, define $f(n)=n+1$.
Do you see why (a) $f$ maps $\Bbb N$ to $A$ and (b) why it does so surjectively?
